# How to use pointers to allocate an array inside another function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I'm 2nd year computer engineer and still in learning process of C language. I'd like to undesrtand how to dynamically alocate an array by using function instead of allocate inside the main.

Here is the code that works when I allocate array inside main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ESC_KEY 27
#define NUM_1_KEY 49
#define NUM_2_KEY 50

void find_two_largest(int a[], int n, int *largest, int *second_largest);
void arrayInit(int *,int *, int, int);
void randGenArray(int [], int);
void inputArray(int[], int);
void result(int, int);
void loading(void);
int menu(void);

int main(void)
{
    system("color f5");
    int n,i,largest,largest_2, *a;

    arrayInit(a,&n, 2, 10);

    if(menu())
        randGenArray(a,n);
    else
        inputArray(a,n);

    find_two_largest(a,n,&largest,&largest_2);
    result(largest,largest_2);
    return 0;
}


void find_two_largest(int a[], int n, int *largest, int *second_largest)
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    system("cls");
    loading();
    *largest = 0;
    *second_largest = *largest;
    for (i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(*largest<a[i])
            *largest=a[i];
    }
    for(j=1;j<n;j++){
        if(*largest==a[j])
            continue;
        else{
            if(*second_largest<a[j])
                *second_largest=a[j];
        }
    }
    return;
}

void randGenArray(int a[], int n)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        a[i]=rand()%100;
        Sleep(10);
        printf("\n>>  Integer %d: %d", i+1, a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n\nPress any key to continue...");
    getch();
    return;
}

void inputArray(int a[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("\n  Please enter integer %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    return;
}

int menu(void)
{
    char _char;

    printf("\n  Please choose one of the following options:\n    1.Fill array manually\n    2.Fill array by random numbers\n\n  ");

    while(1)
    {
        _char = getch();
        switch(_char)
        {
            case ESC_KEY:
                printf("\n\n  Thank you for using our software!\n\n");
                exit(0);

            case NUM_1_KEY:
                system("cls");
                return 0;

            case NUM_2_KEY:
                system("cls");
                return 1;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

void arrayInit(int *a,int *n, int min, int max)
{
    printf("\n  Please enter a length of the array: ");

    do{
    scanf("%d", n);
    if (*n<min||*n>max)
        printf("\nThe ranged is limited. Please enter the value between %d and %d.\n", min, max);
    } while(*n<min||*n>max);

    a = (int*)calloc(*n,sizeof(int));

    return;
}

void loading(void)
{
    printf("\n  Loading");
    printf(".");
    Sleep(300);
    printf(".");
    Sleep(300);
    printf(".");
    Sleep(300);
    system("cls");
    return;
}

void result(int l, int l2)
{
    system("cls");
    printf("\n  Largest = %d     Second Largest = %d",l,l2);
    Sleep(500);
    printf("\n\n\n  Thank you using our software! ;D\n\n");
    return;
}
```

But if you cut and paste this line from arrayInit to main and change *n to n - it will work!

> a = (int*)calloc(*n,sizeof(int));

I'm sorry for asking about so stupid and obvious things but I didn't figure it out by myself. Thank you for any advice.

Comment: `a` is a local variable, which will go out of scope when you return, that is directly after you have allocated memory to it. You need to either pass in a pointer to pointer to int or, maybe simpler, return the newly allocated memory.

Comment: and I forgot to free the memory after finding the values I needed >.<

Comment: I like the `loading` function, by the way.

Comment: `void f(int x) {x = 5;} int main(void) {int i = 7; f(i); printf("%d\n", i); return 0;}` - what do you think this would print, and why?

Comment: @immibis You don't have return; in void. not sure would it be compiled.
but the answer is 7.
Because you changed the value without pointing to the value inside the main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple program which will show you how to do that -

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

void create(int **p,int n);    // function taking arguments as int ** and n is number of elements

int main(void) {
   int *a;     
   int n=5,i;                       // declare and initialize n 
   create(&a,n);             // pass address of a to function
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        a[i]=i;                    // store value of i in a[i]
       printf("%d\n",i);          // print a[i]
    }
   free(a);                      // free the allocated memory
   return 0;
}

void create(int **p, int n){
      *p=calloc(n,sizeof(int));            // allocate memory to *p (type- is int *)
  }
```

[Working Code](https://ideone.com/krTC3H)

Comment: Perfect! that's what i was thinking of. But why you passed the address of a address pointer. If 'a' technically is the address of array?

Comment: @KasparSiricenko I passed address of `int *`  so that it does not go out of scope after function terminates. As M.Ohem described in his comment `a` is local variable so after return it will go out of scope as the function terminates

Comment: @KasparSiricenko `a` in your code is just a pointer  which doesn't point to anything as your code shows .

Comment: I did not get it. :c 
A teacher didn't say anything about scopes. Just said that pointers are addresses to change the value outside the main.

Comment: @KasparSiricenko See if you just pass `a` , it will be pass by value and `p` in function will be local variable , therefore , in that case memory wont be allocated to `a` until you return `p` from the function .

Comment: @KasparSiricenko But if you pass address of `a`  ( _what i did in example_ )so , changes will be made at value stored at address of `a` , therefore , memory will be allocated to `a` itself .

Comment: so in other words you passed to function the address of the address of the array. So when you allocate address of array it will be changed in the address of the address of the array in main, is that right?

Comment: @KasparSiricenko  _First of all make it very clear that **arrays** and **pointers** are not same_.  And yes , if we pass address of pointer , memory is allocated to pointer itself in `main`.

Comment: I got it! Thanks a lot! ;D

Answer (score 0):

You must change your function return type

```
void * arrayInit(int *n, int min, int max)
{
    printf("\n  Please enter a length of the array: ");

    do{
    scanf("%d", n);
    if (*n<min||*n>max)
        printf("\nThe ranged is limited. Please enter the value between %d and %d.\n", min, max);
    } while(*n<min||*n>max);

    return calloc(*n,sizeof(int));
}
```

And call it from `main` in this way: `a = arrayInit(&n, 2, 10);`

Comment: Thanks. but I don't want to return anything.

Comment: @KasparSiricenko The return is the way to assign the heap allocated memory to your main local variable a: you must return it.